# Why does alkyl group withdraw electrons in Grignard reagent?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

R group has electron donating tendencies. Why is it withdrawing?

Answer (score 3):

Is sodium potentallly electron withdrawing?  Given a suitable complexing agent and solvent one sodium atom can withdraw an electron from another that is complexed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide).

Whether something is electron releasing or electron withdrawing depends on its environment.  An alkyl group is slightly electron releasing in some hydrocarbon systems, as when it is attached to a phenyl group.  But that does not carry over to *all* compounds carrying an alkyl group.